# How to extract selected emails specified by attribut of its subject on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

The aim is: extract only first contact emails, not any replies to these emails. It should be possible to identify first contact emails by their respective subject:

"Subject: Order XY ...."

as opposed to other emails which should start with "Subject: Re: Order XY...."  or "Subject: Fwd: Order XY..." or "Subject: Blabla ...."

My Code so far:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("email.com",port)
mail.login(username, password)
mail.select('Inbox.A')
res, msg = mail.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
```

This however retrieves ALL Emails.
Then I tried unsuccessfully various variants of

```
while True:
try:
    msg["Subject"].startswith("Order XY") 
    subject = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0][0]
except: 
    pass
```

Please, could someone help me to implement the above specified condition i.e. to retrieve only first contact emails?

Thanks a million for any advice!

Version: Python3

Comment: why `msg["Subject"].startswith("Order XY") ` does not work for you?

Comment: Can't say. Code gets suspended without clear error message. My guess is that this is caused by a faulty "While True" or "try/except" construct - but I don't know.

Comment: Try to solve this issue first. Maybe you will see that `startswith("Order XY")` works.

Comment: Thanks. Any advice on how?

Comment: maybe the code is stuck in infinite loop in `while True`